# ASP.NET Core MVC: On-Session-expire-event?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET Core we [configure the timeout for sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-session-state) using:

```
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
});
```

Is there an event I can subscribe to to get notified when an old session is abandoned?

Put in other words: What is the .NET Core replacement for `Session_End()` in "Global.asax"?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no session_end event in asp.net core now.

Here is a workaround, we could write a custom middleware to check the request's session is exists or not.

Notice, this middleware will run for each request, like below:

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Session != null)
            {
                var session = context.Session;

                // Check if the session has expired or has been abandoned
                if (!session.IsAvailable)
                {
                    // Trigger your event here
                    OnSessionAbandoned(session.Id);
                }
            }


            await next();
        });
```

Comment: This does not work for me. `session.IsAvailable` is always true but `session.Id` is changing as a new session is initiated. But there is no trace of the old one then.